# How can we connect multiple data sources in QlikView?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to connect multiple data sources (Oracle, MySql etc) and databases. Then I want to create a table in Qlikview based on the result set of multiple select queries from the different databases.

How can we do this?

Comment: Hi has my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the easiest is to create separate ODBC connections in Windows:

[image]

Then in Qlivkiew script before SELECT we have to specify which connection we want to use:

```
ODBC CONNECT TO [Connection Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the results tables to have exactly the same column names then Qlik will automatically concatenate those tables.

So

```
ODBC [ORACLE];

SALES:
Select TransNum as OrderId,
       Amount
from xxxxxx;

odbc [other SQL];

Select OrderId,
   Value as Amount
from yyyyy;

load OrderId,
   Amount
from zzzzz.xls;
```

Will result in one table called SALES with the 2 columns OrderId and Amount